# MoviePy OSError: MoviePy Error with ImageMagick

Tags: python, imagemagick, moviepy

I am working on a reddit youtube video creation script using MoviePy in Python. However, I encountered an error related to ImageMagick during the execution of the code.

The error message I received is:

`Exception has occurred: OSError MoviePy Error: creation of None failed because of the following error:`

`` magick.exe: label expected `@C:\Users\HHHHHH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2zy8buxv.txt' @ error/annotate.c/GetMultilineTypeMetrics/797. . ``

`` .This error can be due to the fact that ImageMagick is not installed on your computer, or (for Windows users) that you didn't specify the path to the ImageMagick binary in file conf.py, or that the path you specified is incorrect OSError: magick.exe: label expected `@C:\Users\HHHHHH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2zy8buxv.txt' @ error/annotate.c/GetMultilineTypeMetrics/797. ``

`During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:`

`File "C:\Users\hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh\Downloads\VSCODE\movie.py", line 84, in <module> txt_clip = (TextClip('\n'.join(lines), fontsize=25, font='Arial', color='white', align='West', size=(830,305)) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ OSError: MoviePy Error: creation of None failed because of the following error:`

`` magick.exe: label expected `@C:\Users\HHHHHH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2zy8buxv.txt' @ error/annotate.c/GetMultilineTypeMetrics/797. . ``

`.This error can be due to the fact that ImageMagick is not installed on your computer, or (for Windows users) that you didn't specify the path to the ImageMagick binary in file conf.py, or that the path you specified is incorrect`

The full code reads:

`from moviepy.editor import * import os from moviepy.config import change_settings import conf`

`Use the specified ImageMagick path`

`change_settings({"IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY": conf.IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY})`

`reddit_text_path = "C:\Users\hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh\Downloads\VSCODE\reddit_text" reddit_text_sound_path = "C:\Users\hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh\Downloads\VSCODE\reddit_text_sound" reddit_text_image_path = "C:\Users\hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh\Downloads\VSCODE\reddit_text_image" static_trans_path = "C:\Users\hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh\Downloads\VSCODE\reddit_transition\statictrans.mp4" reddit_users_path = "C:\Users\hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh\Downloads\VSCODE\output\reddit_users.txt"`

`clips = [] audio_clips = [] image_index = 1`

`text_files = sorted(os.listdir(reddit_text_path)) sound_files = sorted(os.listdir(reddit_text_sound_path))`

`Read the file and split the lines`

`users = open(reddit_users_path, 'r', encoding='latin-1').read().splitlines()`

`Extract the first name from the first line`

`first_name = users[0].split()[0]`

`Trim the first name if it's longer than 7 characters and add "..."`

`if len(first_name) > 7: first_name = first_name[:7] + "..."`

`Create a new list with only the first name`

`trimmedusers = str(first_name)`

`for text_file, sound_file, user in zip(text_files, sound_files, users): text_path = os.path.join(reddit_text_path, text_file) sound_path = os.path.join(reddit_text_sound_path, sound_file)`

`text = open(text_path, 'r', encoding='latin-1').read()`
`audio = AudioFileClip(sound_path)`

## `Set the image path based on the current iteration`

`if text_file == text_files[0]:`
`image_path = os.path.join(reddit_text_image_path, 'reddit_text_01.jpg')`
`author_pos = ('10%', '10%')`
`text_pos = ('center', 'center+100')`
`else:`
`# Determine image based on text length`
`if len(text) <= 100:`
`image_path = os.path.join(reddit_text_image_path, 'reddit_text_02.jpg')`
`else:`
`image_path = os.path.join(reddit_text_image_path, 'reddit_text_03.jpg')`

`if image_path == os.path.join(reddit_text_image_path, 'reddit_text_01.jpg'):`
`# Add author to the image clip`
`author_clip = (TextClip(trimmedusers, fontsize=15, font='Arial', color='#696B6B', align='West', size=(830,305))`
`.set_pos((338, 138))`
`.set_duration(audio.duration))`
`elif image_path == os.path.join(reddit_text_image_path, 'reddit_text_02.jpg'):`
`author_clip = (TextClip(user, fontsize=20, font='Arial', color='white', align='West', size=(830,305))`
`.set_pos((240, 148))`
`.set_duration(audio.duration))`
`elif image_path == os.path.join(reddit_text_image_path, 'reddit_text_03.jpg'):`
`author_clip = (TextClip(user, fontsize=20, font='Arial', color='white', align='West', size=(830,305))`
`.set_pos((200, 35))`
`.set_duration(audio.duration))`

`image_clip = ImageClip(image_path).set_duration(audio.duration)`

`lines = []`
`words = text.split()`
`while len(words) > 0:`
`line_words = []`
`while len(words) > 0 and sum([len(w) for w in line_words]) + len(line_words) + len(words[0]) <= 50:`
`line_words.append(words.pop(0))`

## `Add text to the image clip`

`if image_path == os.path.join(reddit_text_image_path, 'reddit_text_01.jpg'):`

## `Add text to the image clip`

`txt_clip = (TextClip('\n'.join(lines), fontsize=25, font='Arial', color='white', align='West', size=(830,305)) .set_pos((240, 190)) # adjust the position based on the image .set_duration(audio.duration))`

`elif image_path == os.path.join(reddit_text_image_path, 'reddit_text_02.jpg'):`
`txt_clip = (TextClip('\n'.join(lines), fontsize=25, font='Arial', color='white', align='West', size=(830,305))`
`.set_pos((240, 190))`
`.set_duration(audio.duration))`
`elif image_path == os.path.join(reddit_text_image_path, 'reddit_text_03.jpg'):`
`txt_clip = (TextClip('\n'.join(lines), fontsize=25, font='Arial', color='white', align='West', size=(830,305))`
`.set_pos((200, 190))`
`.set_duration(audio.duration))`

`composite_clip = CompositeVideoClip([image_clip, txt_clip, author_clip])`

## `Add the composite clip and static transition clip to the list of clips`

`clips.append(composite_clip)`
`audio_clips.append(audio)`

`if text_file != text_files[-1]:`
`# Add the audio and video from the transition clip`
`trans_video = VideoFileClip(static_trans_path)`
`trans_audio = trans_video.audio`
`clips.append(trans_video)`
`audio_clips.append(trans_audio)`

`Concatenate all the clips in the list`

`video = concatenate_videoclips(clips) audio = concatenate_audioclips(audio_clips)`

`video.audio = audio`

`video.write_videofile("C:\Users\hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh\Downloads\VSCODE\output\reddit_video.mp4", fps=24)`

Thank you guys so much. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

have you installed ImageMagick on your computer? moviepy needs it for rendering movies.

it might be that easy.

Comment: I have. I have installed version 7.1.1-11 and installed legacy dependencies in the downloader.

Comment: Does any kind of rendering video work with moviepy work for you? Try simple code :clip.subclip(start time ,finish time ) . If u don't know this google it.   If it didn't maybe u should reinstall dependencies.   Check one more thing: does the address that u have written  to save file exist?      And please trim your code to make it easier to read.

Comment: I used a generic clip.subclip script and it worked, not sure why this file worked.

Comment: did u render a clip.subcip ? u saved a video file ? 

it worked?

Answer (score 0):

> I got the same error, this worked for me:
>
> 1. First, install ImageMagick, on Ubuntu (you can research the equivalent for Windows, Mac, Fedora,...)

```
sudo apt install imagemagick
```

> 2. Allow read|write privileges for domain="coder" in ImageMagick library, go to /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml (get/search the similar
>    location for Windows), in policy.xml file by setting/inserting:

```
<policymap>
  <!-- other policies -->
  <policymap>
    <!-- other policies -->
    <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="LABEL" />
    <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="MVG" />
    <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="MSL" />
    <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PLT" />
    <policy domain="path" rights="read|write" pattern="@*" />
  </policymap>
```

> Try for other patterns too (pattern="{GIF,JPEG,PNG,WEBP}")